# How To Make An Image Fall Down To The Bottom Of The Screen And Repeat?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a game in Android Studio, but I can't figure out how to make an Image 'fall down' to the bottom of the Android Emulator (or Android Device) then have it restart back at the top and 're-fall'. How can I do this and have the Image be copied so that there is multiple 'falling' Images? I know that this must possibly use the LOOP(); and/or RANDOM(); code. Here is the code I have tried...Lots of the words, in the code, are red...Obviously I typed a lot of stuff incorrectly. Please help!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen1);

     ImageView circle1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle1);

    int xPositions = [285, 100];
    int yPositions = [-13, 30];
    int X = 0;
    int Y = 340;


    draw = function() {


        for (int i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++) {
            noStroke();
            fill(0, 200, 255);
            ellipse(xPositions[i], yPositions[i], 10, 10);
            yPositions[i] += 7;

            if(yPositions[i] > 400){
                yPositions[i] = 0;
                random();
            }
        }

}
```

}

```
private Object function() {
}

private void random() {
}
```

Comment: Down vote:: SO is not a code writing service. At least show some initiative and show the code you have tried. Edit this question with code that shows you have made a reasonable attempt to solve your problem and I will change my vote.

Comment: That looks like an effort.  Changed my vote.

Comment: Can anyone please explain which type of code I should use to make my image ‘fall’ down the Android Emulator/Device screen?

Comment: You should use a View Animation (see Google Docs) in a Runnable combined with a Handler (postDelay). Good luck

Comment: Thanks very much!